# How i can change the background color of gframe in gWidgets?

Tags: r, gwidgets

I am building a GUI in `gWidgets` R, but I need to change background color of a `gFrame` from "gray" to "yellow".
Thanks

Comment: Please help us help you by providing us with a reproducible example (i.e. code and example data), see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example for details.

Comment: This isn't part of the gWidgets API, but usually can be performed with the underlying toolkit. Which toolkit are you using? RGtk2, tcltk, Qt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be something like this

```
library(RGtk2); 
getBlock(fr)$modifyBg(GtkStateType["normal"], "yellow")
```

but that only does the outer most frame. Unfortunately, to do this you need to pack the container into an event box and color that. Here is the pattern:

```
library(gWidgets)
options(guiToolkit="RGtk2")
library(RGtk2) ## needed

w <- gwindow("test")
g <- ggroup(cont=w)

e <- gtkEventBox()
getWidget(g)$packStart(e, expand=TRUE, fill=TRUE)
fr <- gframe("Label")                    # no container
e$add(getBlock(fr))
e$modifyBg(GtkStateType["normal"], "yellow")

gbutton("click me", cont=fr)
glabel("a label", cont=fr)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer
i run your example but appear the next Error in R: `"Error: in checkPtrType(widget, "GtkWidget") :  not found the "getBlock" function"` and  `"Error: not found the "getWidget" function"`

Comment: Sorry, those were introduced in gWidgets2. SHould have tested under the other. Try `getToolkitWidget` for `getWidget` and digging into the object via `widget@widget@block` for `getBlock`.

Comment: now appear yellow the area of ggroup but i need only in gframe

Answer (score 0):

```
library(gWidgets)
 options(guiToolkit="RGtk2")
library(RGtk2) ## needed

w <- gwindow("test")
g <- ggroup(cont=w)

e <- gtkEventBox()
getToolkitWidget(g)$packStart(e, expand=TRUE, fill=TRUE)
fr <- gframe("Label")                    # no container
e$add(widget@widget@block(fr))
e$modifyBg(GtkStateType["normal"], "yellow")

gbutton("click me", cont=fr)
glabel("a label", cont=fr)
```

appear the next Error:*Error en checkPtrType(widget, "GtkWidget") : not found 'widget' obj*

Comment: It is `e$add(fr@widget@block)`, not `e$add(widget@widget@block(fr))`